# c# Gridview remove left column Windows Forms Control

Tags: winforms, datagridview

[image: Gridview]

Ok I have this gridview (poor styling I know), but the problem is the column on the left with the little arrow in it indicating where our selection is. I have tried everything to get rid of that, tried all the properties I could think of etc ... with no luck, I am bound to have missed something.

q) Can this column be removed?
q) If so, how please?

> UPDATE 1

I tried removing the Headers - which I didn't think was the problem and it did not solve the issue. As you can see the left column still exists. Can the left column be removed and if so, how?

[image: Headers-Removed]

> UPDATE 2

The Second Image shows the Row Headers removed (notice - no text saying Description and Details)

The third image (below) shows the result of Column[0] being hidden. (No data loaded) we still see the blank left column, the Description Column is missing (hidden) and we are left with Details...

I am trying to get the first column hidden equivelant of Column[-1] hidden, if that makes any sense.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a row header. It can be removed.
Through designer(or by code) set datagridview's property `.RowHeadersVisible = False`

```
mydatagridview.RowHeadersVisible = False;
```

You can hide this/left column

```
mydatagridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: That only removes the header not the Left column as requested... as you can see from the updated image above.

Comment: Thanks Fabio - will check tomorrow - in the middle of a massive refactoring at the moment :P

Comment: tried that - actually as suspected that removes the Description Column and not the first blank column on the left.

Comment: On your picture three columns: `RowHeader`, `Description` column, `Details` column. `RowHeader` can be hidden, so `Description` column too. What you mean by "Left blank column" ? Please, then show picture with hidden `RowHeader` and `Description` column

Comment: Ok tried again - and it worked - forgive me - marked you up for it... It was RowHeadersVisible as you said.